# Is there a way to let IAR CSPY return an error code defined by executed user program?

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, iar, unity-test-framework

I am using IAR EWARM's cspybat to run some unit tests for my embedded code using Unity. I would like an easy way for my build server to determine if the unit tests passed or failed. Is there a way for CSPY to return a nonzero error code if my unit tests fail? I have tried changing the return value in main() with no change. Is there a function I can call to force an error to be returned?

My cspybat batch file looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.4\common\bin\cspybat" -f "C:\Work\Sandbox\ST\stmicroeval\_iar_ewarm_project\settings\Project.UnitTest.general.xcl" --backend -f "C:\Work\Sandbox\ST\stmicroeval\_iar_ewarm_project\settings\Project.UnitTest.driver.xcl"
```

Comment: Can you use the semi-hosted I/O or a log breakpoint that prints a message? One of those options might get redirected to `stdout` on your server's command line that you could then detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

I've solved this by replacing "exit" with a function that prints a specific pattern, plus the exit code. I then wrapped the call to `cspybat` into a script that 1) strips the output of the extra output and 2) exits with the desired exit code.

Answer (score 0):

It's late 2020 and they still don't offer a mechanism to do this.

We solved it by including a macro file with the contents:

```
execUserExit()
{
__message "program exited with __exit_value = ", __exit_value:%d ;
}
```

And having our own exit variable in the code:

```
extern "C" int __exit_value=0xff;
```

That we set prior to calling `exit()` (though you could just write your own version of `exit()`)

This makes the debugger always print SOMETHING, even if the program crashes on startup.

Then we parse with a python wrapper:

```py
pattern =  "__exit_value =\s([\-|0-9|a-f|A-F|x]*)"
retvalue = int(re.findall(pattern,process.stdout)[0])
```